# What is a good way to grab QKeyEvents in a widget?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard

Using Qt-5.7.0, I would like to have a QSpinBox to set a timeout value.  The value can be in seconds or minutes.  I'll put a QLabel after the SpinBox to say which it is.

Now, when the user is operating the control, I would like it to change from seconds to minutes depending on whether the Shift key is pressed.  So, for example, when the cursor is over the spinbox but no shift, the label will say `Minutes` and the the spinbox number can be incremented or decremented.

However, when the cursor is over the spinbox and shift is pressed, the label will switch to `Seconds`, the spinbox value will change to `previous_value * 60`, and the value can be altered.

Using QtCreator, I placed the QSpinBox and QLabel in a QFrame, so everything's together in the right place, but I don't see any Slots where I can grab the Shift state.  I can check `shift` in the SpinBox `on_SB_valueChanged()` function, but I'd really like the change to happen *when the shift button is pressed*, not just when the value is changed (and I discover that the shift button was pressed).

Is there a standard way of managing something like this?  (I guess I could make a custom widget that does it, but perhaps there's an easier way?)  How can such custom widgets be placed in QtCreator?

Comment: A spinbox supports a prefix and a suffix, so you don't need the label.

Comment: That may be the best solution: a 0-10 minute spinbox, but when you go below 1 minute, it switches to a 0-60 second spinbox, with the current value set at 59.

Comment: You're free to change the suffix just as you do the text on the label :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use an event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) and attach it to a stock widget to intercept the event rather than extending the widget.

Here is some code that should more or less work, although I'd personally prefer to have a small toggle button to switch between minutes and seconds, that would be far more intuitive and less error prone:

```
class Filter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QLabel * l;
  public:
    Filter(QLabel * ll) : l(ll) {}
    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *e) {
      switch (e->type()) {
        case QEvent::Wheel:
        case QEvent::KeyPress:
        case QEvent::KeyRelease:
          if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) l->setText("shift");
          else l->setText("noshift");
      }
      return false;
    }
};

class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
      auto ll = new QVBoxLayout(this);
      setLayout(ll);
      ll->addWidget(l = new QLabel(this));
      ll->addWidget(s = new QSpinBox(this));
      s->installEventFilter(new Filter(l));
    }
  private:
  QLabel * l;
  QSpinBox * s;
};
```

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty good.  Not as easy as the automatic hookup you get by naming your methods appropriately, but easy enough to add.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: It is not a hack, that the official and recommended way to do it.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the shift from the SpinBox?  It doesn't increment/decrement on mouse scroll while the shift key is down.  (Tested in a completely separate spin box with no event filter...it just ignores mouse scrolls if shift is down.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  (You're right that a checkbox or something else would generally be easier to use, but I actually want a semi-secret adjusting mode.  Most people will just use the plain unshifted adjustment, but I need to be able to set by seconds in some cases.)